# How can I get the selected text frame from a UITextView

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, ipad, uipopovercontroller

I'm trying to display an `UIPopoverController` from the rect of a selected text in an `UITextView`, How can I get the selected text `CGRect` ?

Thanks!

Comment: If this question is what I think what it is, UIPopoverController in the title is probably misleading? You want to get the CGPoint from the text selection, it is nothing special to UIPopoverController, right?

Comment: Fixed the title as your suggestion is valid @barley.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

I think `[UITextInput selectedTextRange]` and `[UITextInput caretRectForPosition:]` is what you are looking for.

`[UITextInput selectedTextRange]` returns the selected range in character

`[UITextInput caretRectForPosition:]` returns the `CGRect` of the character range in this input.

`UITextView` conforms to [`UITextInput`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITextInput_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UITextInput) (since iOS 5), so you can use these methods for your `UITextView` instance.

It is going to be something like this.

```
UITextRange * selectionRange = [textView selectedTextRange];
CGRect selectionStartRect = [textView caretRectForPosition:selectionRange.start];
CGRect selectionEndRect = [textView caretRectForPosition:selectionRange.end];
CGPoint selectionCenterPoint = (CGPoint){(selectionStartRect.origin.x + selectionEndRect.origin.x)/2,(selectionStartRect.origin.y + selectionStartRect.size.height / 2)};
```

EDIT : Since the sample code became a little hard to get, I added an image for complementing.

[image: An image that illustrates what local variables represent]

Comment: Small issue, you call it center point but you are actually calculating the bottom right point.

Comment: @Till yeah, originally I thought [UITextInput caretRectForPosition:] will take UITextRange as input, but (as the name suggests) it actually takes UITextPosition. I fixed the sample code, and I think it is now more accurate although a little harder to get. And thanks for the edition!

Comment: You still have a small issue in your center calculation :D ... check the X-coordinate again, the brackets are incorrectly set to calc the center.

Comment: Well, I think it was more or less accurate. I sample coded and it worked as I expected. I AM ignoring the width of selectionXXXRect since it is very small, but other than that, the sample code should calculate approximate center quite okay. I added an image for easier understanding. Please let me know if I am still doing something wrong, or if there is something I can improve...

Comment: Ow, gee - see, your additions made it obvious to me that I was wrong. I think your answer is really well done and should deserve a little extra... Will add a bounty once that is possible.

Answer (score 23):

There are some situations where barley's answer won't actually give the center of the selection. For example:

[image: Screenshot showing an example of where using the caret rects would not be accurate]

In this case you can see the Copy/Paste menu is displaying in the center of the selection, which spans the entire width of the text field. But calculating the center of the two caret rects would give a position much further to the right.

You can get a more precise result using `selectionRectsForRange:`

```
UITextRange *selectionRange = [textView selectedTextRange];
NSArray *selectionRects = [self.textView selectionRectsForRange:selectionRange];
CGRect completeRect = CGRectNull;
for (UITextSelectionRect *selectionRect in selectionRects) {
    if (CGRectIsNull(completeRect)) {
        completeRect = selectionRect.rect;
    } else completeRect = CGRectUnion(completeRect,selectionRect.rect);
}
```

It's also worth clarifying that if you're still supporting iOS 4 and using either of these answers, you'll need to make sure these methods are supported before calling them: `if ([textView respondsToSelector:@selector(selectedTextRange)]) { …`

Comment: You don't actually need the check for CGRectIsNull as CGRectUnion already handles this. According to the documentation for CGRectUnion:

    "If either of the rectangles is a null rectangle, a copy of the other rectangle is returned"

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 5** version:

```
if let selectionRect = textView.selectedTextRange {
        let selectionRects = textView.selectionRects(for: selectionRect)
        var completeRect = CGRect.null
        for rect in selectionRects {
            if (completeRect.isNull) {
                completeRect = rect.rect
            } else {
                completeRect = rect.rect.union(completeRect)
            }
        }
    }
```