# How to get the targetRect from the [UIMenuController sharedMenuController] object

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, ipod

I need to get the targetRect of the [UIMenuController sharedMenuController]. I already try this:

```
[UIMenuController sharedMenuController] addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"targetRect" :NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:NULL];
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to get this for a UITextView or UIWebView? If it is UITextView, this answer might help you.

[How can I get the selected text frame from a UITextView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8683848/how-can-i-get-the-selected-text-frame-from-a-uitextview?rq=1)

You can't get the actual `targetRect` since it is declared private in UIMenuController.