# Finding (x,y) coordinate of specified word in UITextView

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitextview

Here is my contents in UITextView...

==>"A ‘Metropolitan’ dining experience offering exquisite food prepared with attention to visual detail & taste."

Now my question is simple and short,how to find the location(x,y) of a word "experience" within the textview.

Any solution will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Similar to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8683848/how-can-i-get-the-selected-text-frame-from-a-uitextview

Hope its a same as what you wanted !

Comment: @Reefaq..thanks rafeeq,but the solution is hardcoded..i am sure with the use some calculation logic we can achieve it.

Comment: play with the codes then you can achieve it .. you can take that link as a direction to get your solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use sizeWithFont, it suppose to be something like this:

```
NSString *text = textView.text;
NSString *substring = [text substringToIndex:[text rangeOfString:@"experience"].location];
CGSize size = [substring sizeWithFont:textView.font];
CGPoint p = CGPointMake((int)size.width % (int)textView.frame.size.width, ((int)size.width / (int)textView.frame.size.width) * size.height);
```

Comment: i am getting some float value for p.x...what does that p.x meant for?

Comment: p.x suppose to be the x coordinate of the text you want in the whole view. [substring sizeWithFont:textView.font].width is the x coordinate in the textview

Comment: i am getting p.x=1368.000000,my UITextview width itself is 360.000.is there any calculation pending to find the exact (x,y) of the word?

Comment: does your UItextview is one liner or have couple of lines?

Comment: its a multiline UITextview @shem...sorry i should have mentioned it in the question itself...

Comment: I edited my answer, it might fit for your multiline text view.

Comment: @shem...ok thanks will check,
size.width % textView.frame.size.width==>i am getting error for this.."Invalid operands to binary expression ('float' and 'float')"

Comment: fixed in the original post

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
- (CGPoint)getPoint:(UITextView *)textView
{
    NSRange range = [textView.text rangeOfString:@"experience"];

    UITextPosition *beginning = textView.beginningOfDocument;
    UITextPosition *start = [textView positionFromPosition:beginning offset:range.location];
    UITextPosition *end = [textView positionFromPosition:start offset:range.length];
    UITextRange *textRange = [textView textRangeFromPosition:start toPosition:end];
    CGRect rect = [textView firstRectForRange:textRange];
    return rect.origin;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this if you want in Swift

```
    let range: NSRange = (txtView.text as NSString).range(of: text)
    let beginning: UITextPosition? = txtView.beginningOfDocument
    let start: UITextPosition? = txtView.position(from: beginning!, offset: range.location)
    let end: UITextPosition? = txtView.position(from: start!, offset: range.length)
    let textRange: UITextRange? = txtView.textRange(from: start!, to: end!)
    let rect: CGRect = txtView.firstRect(for: textRange!)
```