# How to get the x,y position of an NSRange in UITextView

Tags: ios, swift

Given an NSRange from a UITextView in Swift, how can I retrieve the center coordinates of the rectangle that would wrap it? **All the answers I could find here are for objective-c.**

Comment: It would be the same APIs in either language. Make an attempt to translate the Objective-C code. Post your attempted Swift code and, if needed, the corresponding Objective-C code. Explain what problems you are having with the translation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [Pushp's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50986529/3173307):

```
let range: NSRange = (txtView.text as NSString).range(of: text)
let beginning: UITextPosition? = txtView.beginningOfDocument
let start: UITextPosition? = txtView.position(from: beginning!, offset: range.location)
let end: UITextPosition? = txtView.position(from: start!, offset: range.length)
let textRange: UITextRange? = txtView.textRange(from: start!, to: end!)
let rect: CGRect = txtView.firstRect(for: textRange!)
```

Comment: Normally, Instead of reposting someone else's answer, you close the question as a duplicate. Since it was your own question you should just delete your question since it has already been answered.

Comment: @rmaddy The so-called duplicate is a question tagged with objective-c and its marked-as-correct answer is in objective c. I copied and attributed the answer for those who need an answer in swift. The original answer was under the wrong question and therefore was difficult to find; do you want those having the same problem waste time looking for an answer where it isn't meant to be?