# Positioning a popover in a UIWebView on the iPad

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, uipopovercontroller

I have added a custom action to a UIMenuController. When the action is clicked on, I want a popover to appear similar to how the "Define" action works (see screenshot below).

[image: Popover that appears when the "Define" action is selected on a word]

However, I am unable to get the popover to position itself correctly within the UIWebView. Here is an extract of my code that generates the popover when the user selects the custom action:

```
if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
    popover = [[UIPopoverController alloc]
                         initWithContentViewController:contentController];
    [popover setDelegate:self];
    popover.popoverContentSize = CGSizeMake(240., 60.);
    UIMenuController *menuController = [UIMenuController sharedMenuController];

    [popover presentPopoverFromRect:menuController.menuFrame
                             inView:webView
           permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny
                           animated:YES];
}
```

And here is the result when the device is in portrait mode:

[image: Resulting position of the popover]

As you can see, it's not too bad but I can't get it to align exactly to the selected text; in landscape mode the position of the popover is not even close.

Does anybody know how I can position the popover correctly to the selected text and also have it position correctly when the user rotates the device? SDK version is iOS 6.1.

Comment: Looks good to me. Can you provide an image showing the desired output?

Comment: If you take a look at the first image in my original post, the arrow of the popover is flush with the left hand-side of the text selection; similarly, if it was below, the point of the arrow would be aligned with the bottom of the selected text. In my case the point of the arrow is in the middle of the selected text when (ideally) it should be aligned with the top of the selection.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is going wrong here:

```
[popover presentPopoverFromRect:menuController.menuFrame
                         inView:webView
       permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny
                       animated:YES];
```

You are using the menuController's view as the rect to which to anchor the popover window, whereas what you really want is the rect of the text selection.

You can get the text selection rect like so:

```
- (CGRect) textSelectionRect:(UITextView*)textView
{

    UITextRange *selectionRange = [textView selectedTextRange];
    NSArray *selectionRects = [self.textView selectionRectsForRange:selectionRange];
    CGRect completeRect = CGRectNull;
    for (UITextSelectionRect *selectionRect in selectionRects) {
        if (CGRectIsNull(completeRect)) {
            completeRect = selectionRect.rect;
        } else completeRect = CGRectUnion(completeRect,selectionRect.rect);
    }
    return completeRect;
}
```

(see answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15299923/1375695))

Comment: I am not using a UITextView. The selected text is in a UIWebView.

Comment: @Simon, then you need to use Javascript to get the rect, but the principle is the same. See [this useful explanation](http://zaldzbugz.posterous.com/how-to-mark-or-get-the-highlighted-string-ins/) and also Cassius' answer.

Answer (score 1):

you can use a Javascript code to return the CGRect from selected text. Create a file.js and add this code (or put it on a NSString):

```
// Method that gets the Rect of current selected text
// and returns in a JSON format
var getRectForSelectedText = function(elm) {
    if (typeof elm === "undefined") {
        elm = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
    }

    var rect = elm.getBoundingClientRect();
    return "{{" + rect.left + "," + rect.top + "}, {" + rect.width + "," + rect.height + "}}";
}
```

Load Javascript (file or NSString)

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)theWebView
{
    //Load JS file
    NSString *filePath  = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"file" ofType:@"js"];
    NSData *fileData    = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
    NSString *jsString  = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithData:fileData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    [self.webview stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:jsString];
}
```

Now presents your popover:

```
CGRect rect = CGRectFromString([self.webview stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"getRectForSelectedText()"]);

[popover presentPopoverFromRect:rect
                         inView:webView
       permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny
                       animated:YES];
```

If you need use the rect in your self.view, adjusts the frame:

```
- (CGRect)rectForSelectedText
{
    CGRect rect = CGRectFromString([self.webview stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"getRectForSelectedText()"]);
    rect.origin.x += self.webview.frame.origin.x;
    rect.origin.y += self.webview.frame.origin.y;
    return rect;
}
```

I hope have helped you!

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't work. Here is a [screenshot](http://www.simonbuckle.com/images/Popover.png). Any thoughts?

Comment: Simon, if you send me a test project to explain me what is wrong I can help you better!